# Uncaught Type Error:JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.completecompanyDetails').click(function(){
        var orgname = $("#companyName").val();
                var jsonData = {};
        jsonData.orgName = orgname;
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            data:JSON.stringify(jsonData),
            type:"text",
            method:"POST",
            contentType:'application/json',
            success: function(data){
                window.location.href="/config";
                return true;
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Error!");
                return true;
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I'm getting the following error in the 8th line:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Accessing selectionDirection on an input element that cannot have a selection.
```

Comment: Could you post the HTML code as well here?

Answer (score 2):

type is used to define get or post method. `type :'text'` is not a valid option. What you are setting value on method that will come under type option.

If you want to set data type in which you want to recieve response use `dataType` key. Even in dataType key only xml, json, script, or html are allowed.

See jquery ajax documentation in http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/